# Change telerik:RadTimeBar Intervals Label Color

Tags: wpf, telerik

I'm working with a `telerik:RadTimeBar` and as the title suggests I'm trying to change the color of the Interval's Label Color. The following is my `RadTimeBar`:

```xml
<telerik:RadTimeBar x:Name="PoCTimeBar" Width="450"
                    Height="100"                        
                    HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                    VerticalAlignment="Top"                                                                                     
                    Background="#FF435061"                                    
                    BorderBrush="{x:Null}"
                    BorderThickness="1,0,1,1"
                    Content=""
                    Cursor="Hand"
                    EnableSparklineVirtualization="False"
                    PeriodEnd="{Binding Tab.CurrentPoC.EndDate, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                    PeriodStart="{Binding Tab.CurrentPoC.StartDate}"
                    ScrollMode="None"
                    SelectionEnd="{Binding Tab.CurrentPoC.PickEnd, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                    SelectionStart="{Binding Tab.CurrentPoC.PickStart, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                    SelectionTitleFormatString="{}{0:dd/MM/yy-HH:mm} - {1:dd/MM/yy-HH:mm}"
                    VisiblePeriodEnd="{Binding Tab.CurrentPoC.EndDate, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                    VisiblePeriodStart="{Binding Tab.CurrentPoC.StartDate}">
    <telerik:RadTimeBar.Intervals>
        <telerik:HourInterval />
        <telerik:DayInterval />
        <telerik:MonthInterval />
        <telerik:YearInterval />
    </telerik:RadTimeBar.Intervals>
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
            <Custom:EventToCommand Command="{Binding Tab.IRefreshSpanPoC, Mode=OneWay}" />
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</telerik:RadTimeBar>
```

Could you please help me figure out how to achieve this? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Did you have a look [here](https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/wpf/controls/radtimebar/styles-and-templates/styling-the-items-and-groups)?

Comment: Hi, Corentin. I already had a look. But I wasn't able to comprehend very clearly. I would be very grateful if you could point out the codes that I need to implement. Sorry to bother you but I'm really really new with both telerik and wpf. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have two intervals' header in the `RadTimeBar` control, the top one and the one under it. For the top one you can change its color by setting the `Foreground` of the parent `telerik:ItemControl`, for the bottom one you target the `telerik:GroupControl`:

```
 <Grid>
    <telerik:RadTimeBar PeriodStart="1-Jan-2019 12:00:00 AM"  
                        PeriodEnd="31-Dec-2019 11:59:59 PM" 
                        VisiblePeriodStart="14-March-2019 12:00:00 AM"  
                        VisiblePeriodEnd="11-Nov-2019 11:59:59 PM"  >
        <telerik:RadTimeBar.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="telerik:ItemControl">
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red" />
            </Style>
            <Style TargetType="telerik:GroupControl">
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Blue" />
            </Style>
        </telerik:RadTimeBar.Resources>
        <telerik:RadTimeBar.Intervals>
            <telerik:YearInterval />
            <telerik:MonthInterval />
            <telerik:WeekInterval />
            <telerik:DayInterval />
        </telerik:RadTimeBar.Intervals>
    </telerik:RadTimeBar>
</Grid>
```

[image]

**How do i know this?**

You have two tools to use in these scenarios in addition to the documentation:

- Blend: you select the control> right click and then Edit template > Edit a copy.
- [Snoop](https://github.com/snoopwpf/snoopwpf)

**EDIT**

Here the style applied to your code (with some minor adjustment to the start and end dates):

```
      <telerik:RadTimeBar x:Name="PoCTimeBar" Width="450"
                Height="100"                        
                HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                VerticalAlignment="Top"                                                                                     
                Background="#FF435061"                                    
                BorderBrush="{x:Null}"
                BorderThickness="1,0,1,1"
                Content=""
                Cursor="Hand"
                EnableSparklineVirtualization="False"
               PeriodEnd="31-Dec-2019 11:59:59 PM"
               PeriodStart="1-Jan-2019 12:00:00 AM" 
                ScrollMode="None"
                SelectionEnd="{Binding Tab.CurrentPoC.PickEnd, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                SelectionStart="{Binding Tab.CurrentPoC.PickStart, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                SelectionTitleFormatString="{}{0:dd/MM/yy-HH:mm} - {1:dd/MM/yy-HH:mm}"
                VisiblePeriodEnd="{Binding Tab.CurrentPoC.EndDate, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                VisiblePeriodStart="{Binding Tab.CurrentPoC.StartDate}">
        <telerik:RadTimeBar.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="telerik:ItemControl">
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red" />
            </Style>
            <Style TargetType="telerik:GroupControl">
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Blue" />
            </Style>
        </telerik:RadTimeBar.Resources>
        <telerik:RadTimeBar.Intervals>
            <telerik:HourInterval />
            <telerik:DayInterval />
            <telerik:MonthInterval />
            <telerik:YearInterval />
        </telerik:RadTimeBar.Intervals>
        <!--<i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
                <Custom:EventToCommand Command="{Binding Tab.IRefreshSpanPoC, Mode=OneWay}" />
            </i:EventTrigger>
        </i:Interaction.Triggers>-->
    </telerik:RadTimeBar>
```

**Output**

[image]

**Here without the styles:**

[image]

*Make sure that you aren't applying any other style somewhere else.*

Comment: Hi, SamTheDev. Thanks for the answer. In my case, I have only one interval. I tried both `<Style TargetType="telerik:ItemControl">
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red" />
            </Style>` and 
`<Style TargetType="telerik:GroupControl">
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Blue" />
</Style>`.

When I tried the first one, the labels disappeared. The latter does nothing.

Comment: @Trax works fine at my end, please check out my Edit.

Comment: I tried exactly like you've suggested. I even created a new clean Window and the time bar. But the issue persists. This is also happening when I tried to extract the template through blend. And I didn't make any changes to that template. The labels just disappeared.

Comment: @Trax I can't help if I can't reproduce, could you please create a small demo of the issue a and publish it to a public repo?

Comment: Hi, SamTheDev. Sorry for the slow response. I have created a public repo which contains the View which I'm having problems with.
https://github.com/aungkyaw92/TelerikTimeBarIssue.git
I have commented out the TimeBar styles. Please remove the "<!--  -->" to simulate the issue. Thanks for the help. Really appreciate it.

Comment: @Trax that's the same code on your question, that does work fine for me! try creating a small full sample, move block from your codebase to it, until you have the issue then share that one (full sln project).